# Scatterplots with R studio (ggplot2) - issue with plot points

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, data-conversion

I am having an issue when trying to produce a scatter plot from 2 variables. The data is from an excel file. One column/variable is "Contact Method", where the cell value is text, from a multiple choice option (e.g. phone, email)
Another is a numerical rating, such as from 0-50 for "feel valued"

Here is the code I have used:

```
 ggplot(cxfiltered111) + 
      geom_point(aes(x = ContactMethod, y = CXRecommend, fill = ContactMethod)) + 
      ylab(NULL) + 
      xlab(NULL) +  
      coord_flip() + 
      theme_bw() + 
      labs(title = "Relationship between contact method and feeling valued")
```

[image: Click here for Scatterplot image]
Dataset example is available here - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-i8rulX47mrFtgET_DIW3rsR8ql_xKTh/view?usp=sharing

Of course this isn't correct, I feel this is something to do with the data type (e.g. categorical/factor). However I have no idea how to convert this data to the correct data type to produce a legitimate graph. Please help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) Providing your data (or an example dataset) is always crucial when asking a question in R. I would recommend reading this for some suggestions on how to ask a great question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example-aka-mcve-minimal-complete-and-ver

Comment: Also , you say "Of course this isn't correct". Can you want to be more specific in your issue? Scatterplots are designed for plotting X Y data, not categorical data.

Comment: Hey @ZC-, has my answer solved your problem? Please mark it as accepted if it has :)

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't provided any data to use, here is some sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(Contact = c("Social Media", "Phone", "Other", "Letter", "Email"),
                 Score = sample(1:100,100,replace=T))
```

Now recreating your graph with the basic code (no formatting or changing coordinates):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Contact, y = Score, fill = Contact)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Two problems:

1. You are trying to set the aesthetic of a point will `fill`. You need to change `colour`
2. The bigger problem: I am not sure scatterplots are what you really want to be using for such data. As you have pointed out, the data is categorical.

A boxplot is probably the better way to go about this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Contact, y = Score, fill = Contact)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]